# Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, protractor, travis-ci

I am facing the problem:

**My Project is built on Angular4 with typescript, e2e testing with protractor & karma.**

Travis-ci has this error:

```
[03:34:54] E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (2688)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (1,32): Cannot find module './app.po'. (2307)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (4,1): Cannot find name 'describe'. (2304)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (7,3): Cannot find name 'beforeEach'. (2304)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (11,3): Cannot find name 'it'. (2304)
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts (13,5): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)

The command "ng e2e" exited with 4.
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./node_modules/*", "*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [ "node", "jasmine" ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Node v6.10.3**

**npm v3.10.10**

Please help me.

Comment: You can refer to workaround given [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/615). Not sure if these are the same though. Cheers!

Comment: I update my devDependencies and fix this error!

Comment: It work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617912/tserror-%e2%a8%af-unable-to-compile-typescript

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I had met same issue. First I remove `ts-node` and `typescript` from `package.json`. then,

```
npm install ts-node --save-dev
npm install typescript -g 
npm install typescript --save-dev
```

Comment: just updat ts-node with `npm i ts-node@latest` worked for me. Thx.

Comment: FYI: These commands update typescript and ts-node versions

Comment: Thank, that works for me using Vita in a starting project on React + Express

Comment: Also need to make sure current version of Angular supports installing version of typescript. In my case I had Angular 11, the typescript 4.9.3 was installed, so Angular complained, I had to downgrade to 4.1.5 which is max supported by Angular 11 (at that time).

Comment: just add the tsconfig.json file in the folder. by `tsc --init`. after running the above comands

Answer (score 7):

I came here looking for a solution for a similar error when I updated my typescript version, Mine was not a new project, I am running an angular2 project with `"@angular/cli": "1.2.0"`. I updated my typescript version from `2.0.3` to `2.7.2` and then I was getting similar issues like below while running `ng e2e`.

> ```
> Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
> Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'. (2688)
> Cannot find type definition file for 'grecaptcha'. (2688)
> Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'. (2688)
> Cannot find type definition file for 'moment-timezone'. (2688)
> Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (2688)
> Cannot find type definition file for 'q'. (2688)
> ```

The proposed solutions in this post didn't work for me.

I fixed it by updating `ts-node` to `5.0.1`. Versions above this were giving errors like the one below while running `ng e2e` even though I had `experimentalDecorators` set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`:

> error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning

Apart from the above change, I also changed few lines in `protractor.conf.js`

Changed:

```
beforeLaunch: function () {
    require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'e2e'
    });
},
```

to

```
beforeLaunch: function () {
   require('ts-node/register')
}
```

This is for people who may stumble into this post and the proposed solution doesn't work for them.

Comment: In my case, the issue was missing closing curly brace in one of the spec.ts file.

Comment: Updating ts-node and changing the beforeLaunch method did the trick for me. I'm working on angular 10

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was changing `"jsx": "react-jsx"` to `"jsx": "react"` in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: I was completely missing the tsconfig.json file and once I added it, the issue was resolved

Answer (score 1):

Make sure ts-node isn't interpreting js files. For example if you use knex db migrations and you are pointing knex to js migration files in the build directory, ts-node will throw errors as it tries to interpret js files.

Comment: IDK too much but [this stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68295576/8784518) helped me to tacke my issue. I just googled "ts-node isn't interpreting js files" and I found that Q&A. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just delete `nodes_modules`directory, then I run `npm install`command, and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, find the error has been attached
[image]

**Solution:** Check the `tsconfig.json` and set `"allowJs": false`.

Answer (score -1):

If only the `npm install -g typescript` doesn't work.

Try to do `tsc` in the project folder.

Comment: What it is all about ? Is this solution ?

Comment: I've been work in multiple angular projects some of them use old typescript 3.3 so to make the typescript work we need to run that the "tsc"

Answer (score -4):

This is my solution for this issue: -
Run this command

**npm install -save-dev typescript@2.3.4**

```
npm WARN code_gui@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN code_gui@0.0.1 No license field.

+ typescript@2.3.4
updated 1 package and audited 657 packages in 2.539s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```