# ts-node can't find my type definition files

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

When I run `ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine`  I get these errors:

```
tsc/globals.ts:7:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SugarcubeState'.

7     State: SugarcubeState;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is that global file:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
console.log("global.ts");

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    State: SugarcubeState;
    setup: {};
  }
}

declare const State: SugarcubeState = {
  variables: {}
};

declare const setup: any = {
  variables: {}
};
```

Here is my index.d.ts:

```
type SugarcubeVariables = {
};

type SugarcubeState = { variables: SugarcubeVariables };
```

These are both in the same directory and Visual Studio code is not complaining about anything. Why can't ts-node seem to find my type definition files?

I googled this and found this website: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types   Following its advice, i modified my tsconfig file to have a

```
"typeRoots": ["tsc"],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
```

in it, but it had no effect on the error.  I also tried this:

```
    "types": ["tsc/index.d.ts"],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
```

But again, no difference in the errors I received. How do I get ts-node to recognize my .d.ts files?

PS: If you're wondering why I'm defining things this way, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523944/61624

---

I reread that link and it appears that I need to have a very specific directory structure. The problem is, it says I need but the module name in this directory structure, and given the way I wrote my index.d.ts, i have no idea what to name this directory.

Comment: DId you get anywhere with this @Daniel? I am currently going insane around ts-node and custom declaration files... there are no clear answers anywhere

Comment: **See Also**: [ts-node ignores d.ts files while tsc successfully compiles the project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51610583/1366033)

Answer (score 20):

Enable ts-node `--files` option in `tsconfig.json` like this:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ....
  }
}
```

**Further Reading**:

- [Help! My Types Are Missing!](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/866)
- [ts-node ignores d.ts files while tsc successfully compiles the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878548/8791436)

Comment: You can also add in inside of `tsconfig.json` with `"ts-node": { "files": true }` but make sure you don't use the `files` option to set what files to target, that will disregard any other types.