# TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

Any inputs to solve this error is appreciated.

I have tried solutions from `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965071/error-tserror-%E2%A8%AF-unable-to-compile-typescript` but it is not working for me.

```
/user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts(5,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'compression' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/app.ts(6,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'express-rate-limit' or its corresponding type declarations.
src/app.ts(7,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'helmet' or its corresponding type declarations.

at createTSError (/user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
at reportTSError (/user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
at getOutput (/user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
at Object.compile (/user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
at transformSource (/user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:400:37)
at /user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:278:53
at async addShortCircuitFlag (/user/src/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:409:15)
at async nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:654:22)
at async Hooks.load (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:445:20)
at async ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:20) {
diagnosticCodes: [ 2307, 2307, 2307 ]
}
```

Comment: Did you list these dependencies in your package.json and then run `npm install`?